# How to enforce backup of an .ipa from iPad to iTunes/Mac?

Tags: itunes, backup, ios

Usually, all the .ipas are backup up in the `~/Music/iTunes/Mobile Applications` folder. I accidentally deleted an .ipa in the folder. Now, after syncing, the app is on iPad but the .ipa is *not* backup in the `Mobile Applications` folder. How can I enforce the sync to backup all .ipas to the Mac again?

My iPad is not jailbreak. I want to restore the VLC app (.ipa deleted from Mac) from iPad and install on another new iPhone ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**File - Transfer purchases from "device"** command in the iTunes menu is intended to move all apps as well as any other purchased content to an iTunes library that lacks those items.

Answer (score 0):

Just download it again from iTunes, at no extra charge.

Comment: Except it's no longer on the iTunes App Store.